# how connect to main net with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ether

how connect to mainnet with geth?

I used this command before for rinkeby test network

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "/home/mahdi/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `--rinkeby` parameter. Geth uses the mainnet by default.